# Disable logs "logstash.outputs.elasticsearch"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to disable the continuous warn messages being outputted in the logs as

```
[2022-09-20T20:28:54,604][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
```

I read multiple posts and `xpack.monitoring.enabled: false` seemed to have worked for people. My logstash config is

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
pipeline.ecs_compatibility: disabled
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

But i still keep getting those warn messages. Is there any way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

`xpack.monitoring.enabled` is only useful for shipping monitoring (but not logging !!) data to Elasticsearch.

You can update Logstash log levels either [dynamically like this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logging.html#_update_logging_levels)

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9600/_node/logging?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "logger.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch" : "ERROR"
}
'
```

or directly in the [log4j.properties file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logging.html#log4j2)

```
logger.elasticsearchoutput.name = logstash.outputs.elasticsearch
logger.elasticsearchoutput.level = error
```